# "Success page" text translation on success page

Tags: magento2, localisation, translate

I can't find anywhere, where I can translate "Success Page" text - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsfwyysmts4h4by/Screenshot%202018-03-13%2007.25.45.png?dl=0

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you have more that one language in your website?

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit en_US.csv local file of your theme, you can find the instruction and guides here :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html

Comment: mage_checkout.csv file is doesn't exist in M2 structure. And yes, I tried to add translation into main translation file, but no affect: https://www.dropbox.com/s/clun7t5ffxgw0ty/Screenshot%202018-03-13%2008.10.29.png?dl=0

Comment: did you review the url i have shared ?

Comment: @Brek Clean the cache and then check maybe it's work.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue about translation page title, but i don't know if it's fixed. You can see more [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2951). You can override the file **\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_onepage_success.xml** and add to in the body tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">[TEXT HERE]</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

That **[TEXT HERE]** can be translated in the csv files.